# How to set joint effort limit from systems plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey all!

I'm new to gazebo, which i really like and is really powerful for my application. However, I find navigating the new API documentations quite challenging. But that may be a topic for another post.

Right now I'm trying to set the effort limits of a continuous joint from the `Configure` method of my systems plugin. I know the Entity id of the joint. Does anyone have any pointers how to achieve that from here?

And I would even more appreciate some links on how i could have found that myself from the library reference at https://gazebosim.org/docs, such that I can find things like that in the future!

Any help is appreciated!
Regards,
Till

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29022/how-to-set-joint-effort-limit-from-systems-plugin/) by [tblaha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/168574/tblaha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use the `JointEffortLimitsCmd` [component](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/namespacegz_1_1sim_1_1components.html#a74b9ddd353723bd2a458fffb8a5fd6a7).  We don't have tutorials on using each component, but looking at the [API reference](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/namespacegz_1_1sim_1_1components.html) for the component namespace would be a good place to start in the future.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tblaha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/168574/tblaha/) on 2023-04-28**:
Thanks for the fast response and the links, I got it working!

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-05-03**:
Do you have any suggestions on how gazebosim.org/docs could be improved so it would be easier to find the API reference?